# JavaScript:strange behavior of Objects

Tags: javascript

```
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25};
person.fname; //it gives a output John

for (x in person)
  {
  alert(person[x]); //works fine
  person.x;    //incorrect why???
  }
```

Can someone please explain the exact logic behind this?

Comment: `person.x` works the exact same way as `person.fname` (which you seem to be okay with)

Comment: I think it might be better if you also explain why you considered the behaviour to be strange and "person.x" to be incorrect, so that other JavaScript learners that stumbled upon this question can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25};

for (var x in person) {
    alert(person[x]); 
}
```

In the loop x assumes three different values: *fname*, *lname* and *age*. By doing `person[x]` you're trying to access three different properties. It's like doing `person['fname']`, `person['lname']` and `person['age']`. They are the same thing to `person.fname`, `person.lname` and `person.age`, which are **defined properties** of the person object. If you do `person.x` you're trying to access an undeclared property `x` which correctly returns `undefined`.

The usage of `[]` is also known as **bracket notation**, which is needed in the case of iterations and other things, like setting a dynamic property to an object given by user input(for example), but they have a large usage range.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Javascript can't decide **if you want to access the x** property of object person (for example if person={x:100,y:65}), **or the property that is the value of the string** x.

- person[x] will evaluate x to it's value
- person.x will take the property x

Answer (score 0):

`person.fname` will give you `fname` object of `person` object.

`person.lname` will give you `lname` object of `person` object.

`person.age` will give you `age` object of `person` object.

```
for (x in person)
      {
        alert(person[x]);    
      }
```

it'll iterate through the person object.
While in `person.x;` 'x' is an unknown property to person object.

*It is better you should go through some basic javascript concepts, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_quick_guide.htm) and [here](http://www.echoecho.com/javascript.htm).*